# Is this claim about Turkey's restriction on Zorok TV accurate?

Tags: television, culture

> Kurdish children's channel Zarok TV to be allowed back on air in
>   Turkey only if 40% of the shows are promoting Turkish culture and
>   language.

[image]
https://twitter.com/DrPartizan_/status/794858112759058432

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, only 20% needs to be Turkish for children's cartoons, 40% is for something other than children's cartoons (maybe someone who reads Turkish can translate exactly what the 40% is for, either non-children's cartoons or children's programs other than cartoons).

> [EN AZ YÜZDE 20’Sİ TÜRKÇE OLACAK](http://www.cumhuriyet.com.tr/haber/turkiye/626342/Kurtce_Sunger_Bob_da_geri_adim.html#)
>
> RTÜK yasasına göre hazırlanan yönetmelikte 5 yıl önce yapılan bir değişikliğin 2 Kasım’da yürürlüğe girdiği öğrenildi. Yayın Hizmeti Usul ve Esasları Hakkındaki Yönetmelik, 2 Kasım 2011’de yürürlüğe girmişti. Yönetmelikte, çizgi filmler ve çocuk programlarına ilişkin düzenmelere ilişkin televizyon kanallarına geçiş için 5 yıllık süre tanındı. Süre, 2 Kasım’da sona erdi. Buna göre, genel ve tematik içerikli yayın yapan televizyon kuruluşları çizgi filmlere yer vermeleri halinde en az yüzde 20’si Türkçe olacak. Bu kanallardaki çizgi film dışındaki diğer çocuk programlarının da en az yüzde 40’ı Türkçe yapımlardan oluşacak. Bu çizgi film ve çocuk programlarının Türk kültürünü yansıtması da zorunlu tutulacak. Televizyon kanalları, çocuk yayınlarının yayınlanma saatleri ve sürelerine yönelik istatistiksel veriler ile üretim yerine ilişkin bilgileri aylık dökümler halinde RTÜK’e bildirilecek. 5 yıllık geçiş sürecinin son bulması nedeniyle RTÜK, önceden kendisinden lisans almış televizyon kuruluşları ile TRT’yi uyardı.